# Split a list based on common values

Tags: r

I have a list with hundreds of items, each item has two values, like so:

```
x <- list(c(123, 4), c(456, 4), c(124, 3), c(157, 3), c(123, 3), c(456, 3))

[[1]]
[1] 123   4

[[2]]
[1] 456   4

[[3]]
[1] 124   3

[[4]]
[1] 157   3

[[5]]
[1] 123   3

[[6]]
[1] 456   3
```

I want to do two separate things to this data:

1) Split it into multiple lists based on the common second value, giving:

```
> x1
[[1]]
[1] 123   4

[[2]]
[1] 456   4

> x2
[[1]]
[1] 124   3

[[2]]
[1] 157   3

[[3]]
[1] 456   3

[[4]]
[1] 123   3
```

2) Merge it into a shorter list based on the first value, giving:

```
> x3
[[1]]
[1] 123   3   4

[[2]]
[1] 456   3   4

[[3]]
[1] 124   3

[[4]]
[1] 157   3
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to do the second thing, and the first thing I thought I figured out but it doesn't work:

```
y <- list()
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  if(unique(x[[i]][2])){
# if(x[[i]][2] == 4){
    y[[length(y)+1]] <- x[[i]] }}
```

If I run with `unique()` then `y` is returned the same as `x` which is no good. If I run with the hashed-out line instead then I get the right result but obviously only for those instances where `[[i]][2] == 4`. I think `unique()` is probably the wrong thing to use but the right direction. Any idea what to use instead?

Comment: Why don't you just use a `data.frame`?

Comment: the data is output from some igraph functions and...let's say it's resistant to the idea of dataframes. but I did spend a fair amount of time trying to see if i can make use of dataframes instead of lists and it wasn't possible.

Comment: For your frst task, ```split(x, sapply(x, `[`, 2))```

Comment: Do you actually need "x1" and "x2"? Or are those just to help you get to "x3"?

Comment: @ec1013 if it's an output from igraph,I assume it's a graph (directed or not), why not working with graph controls instead of doing all the work outside ? (we'll need a reproducible code giving this kind of output to answer)

Comment: @Tensibai if you know a way to do what I want in igraph I would be much obliged: `x[[1]][1]` refers to an item in another list, where each item contains three nodes that make up a cycle. `x[[1]][2]` refers to a different list whose items contain nodes that make up communities. I'm investigating the presence of cycles between vs within communities.

Which answers @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 's question: Yes, I need both because `x1` tells me intra-communal cycles while `x2` gives me inter-communal ones.

At this point I'm just trying to get data structured in a way that makes it easier to plot.

Comment: If you're intrigued I can post another question with replicable data etc, I just didn't want youse to do my work for me. =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest shaping your data into a data.frame (or tidyverse tibble)

```
library(tidyverse)
x = list(c(123, 4), c(456, 4), c(124, 3), c(157, 3), c(123, 3), c(456, 3))
first = vapply(x, `[[`, numeric(1), 1)
second = vapply(x, `[[`, numeric(1), 2)
elt = seq_along(x)
tbl = tibble(elt = elt, first = first, second = second)
```

and operating on that, perhaps re-thinking the need for 'separate lists', etc. E.g., `group_by()` to impose the grouping and `summarize()` to form a column containing lists of second elements

```
tbl %>% group_by(first) %>% summarize(values=list(second))
```

... but maybe the column of lists created by the `summarize()` statement is now redundant in your subsequent work flow? E.g., the count and mean by group is `summarize(n = n(), mean = mean(second))`.

Comment: `tbl = tibble(elt = elt, first = first, second = second)` returns an error:
Error: Columns `first`, `second` must be length 1 or 12, not 6, 6

Comment: Could you explain what `'[['` does in vapply please?

Comment: For a vector `x = c(1, 2, 3)`, `x[[1]]` extracts the first element. So the `vapply()` is iterating across the elements of the list x, and for the ith one it is extracting the first (`[[, ..., 1`) or second (`[[, ..., 2`) element; it is like @minem's function, `vapply(x, function(x) x[[1]], numeric(1))`, but written as `vapply(x, function(x, i) x[[i]], numeric(1), 1)` and then, because `[[` is actually a function (see `get("[[")`), replacing the function-calling-a-function with `vapply(x, `[[`, numeric(1), 1)`.

Comment: For a somehow similar result you can do `x2 <- x %>% do.call(rbind,.) %>% as_tibble %>% nest(V2)`. Or to get your result : `x2 <- x %>% do.call(rbind,.) %>% as_tibble %>% nest(V2) %>% mutate_at("data",.%>% map(.%>% unlist))`

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this:

```
x1 <- split(x, sapply(x, function(x) x[[2]]))
```

and this:

```
x2 <- split(x, sapply(x, function(x) x[[1]]))
x2 <- lapply(x2, function(x) c(x[[1]][1], unique(sapply(x, function(y) y[[2]]))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
data.table(do.call(rbind, x))[, list(new = list(c(V1, V2))), V1]$new
## [[1]]
## [1] 123   4   3
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] 456   4   3
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] 124   3
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] 157   3
##
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep it strictly in lists, purrr is handy:

```r
library(purrr)

x <- list(c(123, 4), c(456, 4), c(124, 3), c(157, 3), c(123, 3), c(456, 3))

x1 <- split(x, map_dbl(x, 2))

str(x1)
#> List of 2
#>  $ 3:List of 4
#>   ..$ : num [1:2] 124 3
#>   ..$ : num [1:2] 157 3
#>   ..$ : num [1:2] 123 3
#>   ..$ : num [1:2] 456 3
#>  $ 4:List of 2
#>   ..$ : num [1:2] 123 4
#>   ..$ : num [1:2] 456 4

x2 <- x %>% 
    split(map_dbl(., 1)) %>% 
    modify_depth(2, ~.x[-1]) %>% 
    simplify_all() %>% 
    imap(~c(as.integer(.y), .x))

str(x2)
#> List of 4
#>  $ 123: num [1:3] 123 4 3
#>  $ 124: num [1:2] 124 3
#>  $ 157: num [1:2] 157 3
#>  $ 456: num [1:3] 456 4 3
```

Probably more usefully, purrr can quickly turn the list into a tidy data frame so you can do these tasks via grouped operations:

```r
df_x <- x %>% map_dfr(~list(x = .x[1], y = .x[2]))
# or equivalent but more programmatic,
df_x <- x %>% map_dfr(compose(as.list, set_names), c('x', 'y'))

df_x
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1   123  4.00
#> 2   456  4.00
#> 3   124  3.00
#> 4   157  3.00
#> 5   123  3.00
#> 6   456  3.00
```

via `dplyr::group_by` and `summarise` or `tidyr::nest` or what have you.